# Turn off a script in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a document I'm working on as part of a much larger site. A lot of scripts are loaded in automatically, but one is breaking things and I don't know how it's included. I can't remove it because it's needed elsewhere (it does event listeners), but it serves no purpose for the part of code I'm running other to cause a pointless page refresh which ruins the users' work (and then, only in chrome).

To that end, is there a way in javascript to turn off another source script, and then turn it back on later?

I don't have the option of modifying the target script itself or keep it from being initially included in the document.

Comment: nope sorry. there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Can you control what order the scripts load in?

Comment: @Bioto Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of...

you can always store any JavaScript method inside a variable, replace it's implementation, do your own stuff and finally restore it.

From your question it is unclear if this might be a solution for your Problem, I just mention this because of all the "Not possible" comments.

https://jsfiddle.net/3grfL30s/

```
function alertSomething(cp){
  alert("TEST: " + cp);
}


alertSomething(1);
// from here i dont want alerts, no matter what code is calling the method
// backup method to "x" to restore it later.
var x = alertSomething;
alertSomething = function(){} //overwrite alertSomething to do nothing

//do my work, verify alertSomething is doing nothing
alertSomething(2);

//restore alert method
alertSomething = x;

//verify its working agian
alertSomething(3);
```

This would produce the alerts `1` and `3`, even if `2` would have been called while your code is beeing executed.

For more complex methods or non-boolean execution conditions, the Proxy Pattern with additional "flags" can be useful (Example still boolean, but there could be multiple conditions):

https://jsfiddle.net/3grfL30s/1/

```
function alertSomething(cp){
  alert("TEST: " + cp);
}

var doIt = 1;
var originalAlert = alertSomething;
alertSomething = function(cp){
  if (doIt){
    return originalAlert.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

alertSomething(1);
// in here i dont want alerts
doIt = 0;

//do my work, verify alertSomething is doing nothing
alertSomething(2);

//restore alert method
doIt = 1;

//verify its working agian
alertSomething(3);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the best idea I've seen so far. Doesn't fully solve my problem, but definitely gets me a step closer. Thanks!